# jQuery function not working on one page only

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a smooth scrolling jQuery function that works on all pages but one. The link to the page that does not work is below. The blue 'Free Tests' link in the subnav is the one not working. Has anyone had this odd problem before, and what could be causing it?

http://tinyurl.com/c364wwx

Comment: How about you post some code that may cause this problem? I doubt that anybody will look through the whole site... BTW, have you checked the console output? There is an error.

Comment: Sorry, I was waiting for this comment - but as I don't know what was causing it, the bits I would have included for the smooth scrolling function were not the bits that has this issue. What could I have done other than added the link to the page? And yep checked the console error but didn't understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove noconflict declaration, or change code in goToByScroll function to:

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 
                            jQuery("#"+'freeTest').offset().top
                            },'slow');
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for that, I had left that jQuery.noConflict(); from the previous site. I have removed it now. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

You page is importing jQuery and then calling `jQuery.noConflict()`.  Thus there's no `$` symbol but that's apparently what your code expects. There's an error reported in the console.

The version of jQuery you're using is very, very old.

Comment: Which bit is old, am I not using the latest version 1.7.2?

Comment: That's jQueryUI. It's a little old, but the jQuery library itself is 1.3.2.  That predates the release of IE9. (It's from February 2009.)

Comment: oh :s damn - I need to update that then. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to go off topic but what's the difference between jQueryUI and a non UI link?

Comment: jQuery is the base library. jQueryUI provides UI widgets (dialogs, fancy buttons, datepicker, sliders, etc).

Comment: okay sweet, so you would always need to include both latest versions if what you are doing with jQuery is UI?

Comment: Well there are dependencies; newer versions of the UI library rely on features in newer versions of the base library. You don't always need to be 100% up-to-date, but 1.3.2 is pretty old. The current version is 1.8.  Now be warned that there have been changes over the past three years that may cause some older code to break.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the heads up. I will make sure I check everything still works :)

Answer (score 3):

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
```

That's because you have

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Remove it.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ if you want more information.

Answer (score 3):

You have `jQuery.noConflict();` activated, either remove this line or use jQuery() instead of $. (also check the console for errors)